# Full polys vs. hybrids (poly and natural gut)

Tags: tennis

What are the differences between using a hybrid string setup of natural gut and polyester strings, compared to a full bed of polys?

Answer (score 1):

**Natural Gut/Poly (Mains/Crosses)**

A gut/poly hybrid will be incredibly friendly on the arm, while also providing a boost in power due to the gut being in the mains. Control and spin will be lacking compared to many other stringing setups.

**Poly/Natural Gut (Mains/Crosses)**

In general, players should find that a poly/gut hybrid will highlight the spin/control friendliness of poly, with the comfort of the natural gut. This is especially true for players with a lot of topspin on their ground strokes.

**Full Poly**

There are hundreds of options when it comes to a full bed of poly, so any claims here will have to be generalized when compared to *other* string materials.

A full bed of poly will in general provide better access to spin and control. There are polys that are shaped (square, hexagonal, etc) to provide more "bite" on the ball, thereby increasing spin potential.

A downside of poly is the tension maintenance. A full bed of poly will have an initial drop off in tension, where after it can sit until you either break a string or the break the racquet.

Many players also complain about the arm-friendliness of full poly bed. I personally have suffered through tennis-elbow when using some polys, and have since found certain brand offerings that can provide more comfort.

**Caveats**

All this being said, there are way more specificities that players can dive into with respect to stringing (main/cross tension disparity, changes in tension to affect launch angle, temperature at play, etc).

Stringing is a highly personal preference and the best advice I can give is to try out many combinations to get a feel for what changes affect your game.